# facebook share dialog redirecting instead of popping up?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I have a dynamically generated facebook share button link being generated in JS, here is the url of the button:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=someAppId&display=popup&href=' + window.location.href;

That all works fine.

My issue is that the "display=popup" parameter in the links query string does not do as it says, instead it redirects to a sharing page when I expect it to popup.

What's more, when I submit the share, I do not get redirected back to my site.

I am new to the facebook sharing SDK and to be honest am getting quite stressed with it.

All I want is a simple share button (I made a custom styled button which is why I use a dynamically generated HREF) that doesn't mess with UX and works, surely it cannot be so complex to ask for?

So in short:

1) How do I make the share dialog popup instead of redirect?

2) If there is no way to stop it redirecting, how do I get it to redirect back once a share is submitted?

3) Is there a problem with the way I have done this?

4) What recommendations would you make if this were your project?

5) Is there simpler documentation or a tutorial series that you may know of for the facebook sharing SDK? Because the docs on the developer site are pretty unclear and hardcore in places, I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is that the "display=popup" parameter in the links query string does not do as it says, instead it redirects to a sharing page when I expect it to popup.

You misunderstood what this parameter does.

Of course browsers don’t open a *normal link* as a popup, just because the URL in the href attribute might or might not contain certain parameters.

The purpose of this parameter is to tell the dialog what setting it *will be shown in* – and if that’s `popup`, then the dialog elements are rendered smaller than they would be in the full page version.

> 1) How do I make the share dialog popup instead of redirect?

By either opening the target URL in a popup yourself (`window.open`), or by using the JS SDK instead, `FB.ui` can be used to call the dialogs and will open a popup to do so.

> 2) If there is no way to stop it redirecting, how do I get it to redirect back once a share is submitted?

For the URL version it is mandatory to specify the `redirect_uri` parameter, to tell the dialog where to redirect back to after sharing.

Comment: Do you have an example of, for example: user clicks an `a` tag, the FB.ui opens a dialog without redirect? really struggling with this documentation on the facebook dev site, it is honestly some of the worst documentation in terms of clarity that I have ever read.

Comment: Documentation for the JS SDK has pretty simple and clear examples.

Comment: Not from what I am seeing, it is far to undetailed and seems very assumptive and I cannot find clear examples anywhere else.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui has examples on how to call the dialogs. An executing something when an element on your page is clicked, by assigning a click handler to the element, should not be news to you, right?